# Where Can I Find a Full Set of Metikat Hapri?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

There is an excellent set of green hard cover seforim (super commentary) by R. Refael Lofer on parts of Pri Megadim called Metikas Hapri. I own one volume. Where in the US can one locate a full set?

Comment: https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%92-%D7%94%D7%9C-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%92-%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%98

Comment: @אילפא thx. I own that volume.

Comment: Who said that he wrote more then one volume.

Comment: @ Efrayim - he has written more than one volume; I have seen the set.

Comment: Check in the page after the title page a lot of times there is contact information to the author or distributor